# Git move code between branches to master

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

I have a Git repository with `master` branch and two other branches `A`, `B`.

For some reason the codes in `master`, `A`, `B` is completely different.

I need to place code from `A`, `B` branches to `master` and delete `A`, `B` Branches.

Please guide me in achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout master
git merge A
git merge B
git branch -D A B
```

This should take care of things assuming you have no merge conflicts.

Comment: Thank You gavin for quick response. I have tried this
This makes master code disappear, I'm able to see both A,B code

Comment: The code from A or B must be changes to master. Try: `git diff master..A` and `git diff master..B` and you will see what Git is seeing as changes that will be made when merging.

Comment: All source files are deleted with comments 'deleted file mode 100644'

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but it sounds like everything you have in master has been deleted in one of the other branches.

Comment: Using the `-D` option of `git branch` you risk deleting unmerged branches and losing you commits! It is a shortcut of `-d --force` where `-d` would normally only delete so called "fully merged" branches. Be careful.